# converting txt file to zip file in TCL

Tags: base64, tcl

i convert zip binary file to base64 txt file using other code. Now I want to convert the base64 txt file back to zip file using below code. but the resultant zip file display error. How can I solve this

```
proc b64en str {
set bits $str 
set tail {}
return [string  map {
    A 000000 B 000001  C 000010  D 000011 E 000100 F 000101 
    G 000110 H 000111 I 001000 J 001001 K 001010 L 001011 
   M 001100 N 001101 O 001110 P 001111 Q 010000 R 010001 
   S 010010 T 010011 U 010100 V 010101 W 010110 X 010111 
   Y 011000 Z 011001 a 011010 b 011011 c 011100 d 011101 
   e 011110 f 011111 g 100000 h 100001 i 100010 j 100011 
   k 100100 l 100101 m 100110 n 100111 o 101000 p 101001 
  q  101010 r 101011 s 101100 t 101101 u 101110 v 101111 
   w 110000 x 110001 y 110010 z 110011 0 110100 1 110101 
   2 110110 3 110111 4 111000 5 111001 6 111010 7 111011 
    8 111100 9 111101 + 111110 / 111111 
} $bits]$tail   
}
proc callme {file1 file2} {   
set file1 [open $file1 r]
set file2 [open $file2 w+]
fconfigure $file2 -translation binary 
fconfigure $file1 -buffering line  
while {[gets $file1 data]>=0} {      
   set var $data
   set nvar [string trimright $var = ]
   set nvar [string trimright $nvar = ]
   set var2 [b64en $nvar]
   set var3 [binary format B* $var2]
   puts $file2 $var3    
}
close $file1
close $file2
}
set fp1 [lindex $argv 0]
set fp2 [lindex $argv 1] 
callme $fp1 $fp2
```

The above code is working for txt to txt file
please help me.
Thanks
[when in open resultant zip file it display this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auuGP.png)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use some zip and base64 tcllib modules: see [this](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc0.html#file) and [this](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc0.html#text_processing)

Comment: Tcl 8.6 includes both base64 and compression support. Not full zip, but the zlib algorithm core so that the rest is “trivial”. But I'd just call a external `zip` program if possible because I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing binary data, I think you need to specify -nonewline, otherwise you'll have extra newline characters in the binary file, and the data will be corrupt.

```
puts -nonewline $file2 $var3
```